# Efficiently storing and getting likes in FireStore / Document DB

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have a page with posts and likes for each post.

In FireStore a collection of posts and a collection of likes, and I update the total_likes and recent likes array when a user likes or unlikes a post with cloud functions.

However, I can't figure out how to show for each post if the currently logged in user liked it or not. What's an efficient way to do that for.

Any pointers?

Comment: So if I had a where IN query I could when loading the posts page run a query against the likes collection and fetch all the likes which have the user_id and post_id in them. But firestore doesn't have IN or OR. so how can I model the data differently to be able to support this use case ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you might need to look at data aggregration. Even though this example is with Angular, I also use the same principle in a different application: https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/firestore-cloud-functions-data-aggregation/

Alternatively, you could store the post_id's that your user likes in their own 'like_array'. Knowing which posts the user currently sees, you can cross reference the shown post_id's with the (single object) 'like_array' from the user to determine if he/she has liked a particular post. In the long run, you could disambiguate like_arrays based on days or weeks, and only query the like_arrays of this and last day/week - based on what post you are showing. If you are working with categories of posts, similar applies: different like_arrays for different categories.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think this is probably the best approach, as most posts on a page will be chronological. It's makes my mind hurt to think about all this denormalization. but I guess the key in FB is to denormalize the hell out of the data.

Answer (score 3):

One solution would be to have another collection in your Firestore database where you create a document by user, in which you save (and update) **an object** containing all the posts this user has liked.

Like

```
- likers    (Collection)
   - UserUID (doc)
      -  postIds {
             post1_UID: true,
             post2_UID: true 
         }
```

The idea is to use the technique described in the doc, here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/arrays#solution_a_map_of_values

I don't know which language you use in the front end but in JavaScript you would do:

```
var postToTestId = ....;  <- You set this value as you need (e.g. as a function parameter)
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword("...", ".....")
    .then(function (info) {
        var postId = 'azer';
        return db.collection('likers')
            .where('postIds.'+ postToTestId, '==', true)
            .get();
    })
    .then(function(querySnapshot) {
        if (querySnapshot.size > 0) {
            console.log("USER LIKES THIS POST!!!");
        }
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

I don't think there is any solution without storing somewhere all the posts each user liked...

Comment: But this means if I have 30 products per page i'm going to hit FireStore with 30 queries for every page the user loads just for the likes.

Comment: @Unenumrated If you mean 30 "posts" per page for a given user, yes you will have, for each post, to query the DB in order to know if it was liked by the user.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant, That's going to be very slow, 30 http requests just for the likes and also pricing on freebase is going to kill the idea if it gets traction...

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Thank you. Your solution fits my use case.Could you to share your views on calculating count of LIKE and handling UNLIKE (after LIKE is hit) in terms of count.

Comment: @Unenumrated I think you can do it with one query, load all the likes of given user at the start and they just check if postid is in that list or not, if yes show like icon selected.